# Adjust the results of evaluating Table so it can be used as a argument to Point

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list generated by `Table` as below.

```
Table[{a x1 + b x2 + c x3, a y1 + b y2 + c y3, a z1 + b z2 + c z3}, 
  {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}, {c, -5, 5}]
```

but it can't be used as an argument to `Point`. That is,

```
Point[
  Table[{a x1 + b x2 + c x3, a y1 + b y2 + c y3, a z1 + b z2 + c z3}, 
    {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}, {c, -5, 5}]]
```

doesn't work. How do I adjust the list returned by `Table` to make compatible with `Point`?

Comment: Look up `Flatten[]`.

Comment: `Flatten[Table[{a x1 + b x2 + c x3, a y1 + b y2 + c y3, 
   a z1 + b z2 + c z3}, {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}, {c, -5, 5}], 2]` works fine! Problem solved.

Comment: Since you've figured it out, please write an answer to your question. :)

Answer (score 4):

An answer has been given in the comments to the OP, but I will elaborate on it a little. I will make use a reduced data set to make this answer a little more concise.

```
a = Table[{a x1 + b x2 + c x1, a y1 + b y2 + c y1, a z1 + b z2 + c z1},
  {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {c, -1, 1}];
```

This produces a list of depth 4:

```
ArrayDepth[a]
```

> 4

but what is wanted as the argument for `Point` is list of depth 2, i.e., a list of 3D points. That means the list must be flattened at top-level twice.

```
Point@Flatten[a, 2]
```

> ```
> Point[{  
>    {-2 x1 - x2, -2 y1 - y2, -2 z1 - z2},  
>    {-x1 - x2, -y1 - z2},  
>    {-x2, -y2, -z2},  
>    {-2 x1, -2 y1, -2 z1},  
>    {-x1, -y1, -z1},  
>    {0, 0, 0},  
>    {-2 x1 + x2, -2 y1 + y2, -2 z1 + z2},  
>    {-x1 + x2, -y1 + y2, -z1 + z2},  
>    {x2, y2, z2},  
>    {-x1 - x2, -y1 - y2, -z1 - z2},  
>    {-x2, -y2, -z2},  
>    {x1 - x2, y1 - y2, z1 - z2},  
>    {-x1, -y1, -z1}, {0, 0, 0},  
>    {x1, y1, z1},  
>    {-x1 + x2, -y1 + y2, -z1 + z2},  
>    {x2, y2, z2},  
>    {x1 + x2, y1 + y2, z1 + z2},  
>    {-x2, -y2, -z2},  
>    {x1 - x2, y1 - y2, z1 - z2},  
>    {2 x1 - x2, 2 y1 - y2, 2 z1 - z2},  
>    {0, 0, 0},  
>    {x1, y1, z1},  
>    {2 x1, 2 y1, 2 z1},  
>    {x2, y2, z2},  
>    {x1 + x2, y1 + y2, z1 + z2},  
>    {2 x1 + x2, 2 y1 + y2, 2 z1 + z2}  
> }]
> ```